# managing form manipulation by id javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have a basic weekly schedule form for a fake app, and I want to track the users clicking the select boxes and what they pick. As in the picture below, if the form started with 12:00 and 12:15, I want to keep track of if they change both of the times in javascript. I have an idea of what to do except how to keep track of it...am I using the for, id, or name attributes, why do I use one and not the others, and what javascript functions are good to do this? I have no framework installed but Django

```
<form id="schedule_form" method="post"  action="/owners/artemis-treats/schedule/"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <span>Monday</span>
        <p><label for="id_open_time_1">Opening:</label> <select id="id_open_time_1" name="open_time_1">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="00:00" selected="selected">12:00 a.m.</option>
<option value="00:15">12:15 a.m.</option>
<option value="00:30">12:30 a.m.</option>
<option value="00:45">12:45 a.m.</option>
```

Thank you

[image: display]

Comment: Do you only want to know just if it's changed? Or do you want to know what the old and new values are? Are the original values set by a Django-generated form? Are you attempting to store value changes in Django or just use a "change" flag to run a script?

Comment: Hi nibble, I just want to know when it gets changed to something else (without the form being submitted). The original values come from a django form, and get populated with the weekly schedule. I want to use 2 changes (of opening and closing time) to set all other days to those times

Comment: when I change the times without submitting the form and view source, the "selected" value doesn't change like I expected it to. I guess it only changes on submission of form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to jQuery, you could do something along these lines to determine when or if the default selected value has changed:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // Save default select value on page load.
    var default_select = $('#id_open_time_1').val();

    // When it changes, test to see if change is different from default.
    $('#id_open_time_1').change( function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === default_select )
            alert('It has NOT changed! Default is selected.');
        else
            alert('It changed from default!');
    });
});
```

View example is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu44188L/2/).

Comment: By the way, this would go inside a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag in your HTML.